# H2 DB and Flyway DB Migration using Spring

Tags: spring-boot, h2, flyway

As am learning i am creating a simple application which uses H2 database to store a table using spring boot. I am using flyway to migrate/create a new table from JAVA program.  I have specified the below properties in the 'application.properties' file:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
server.port=8080

spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/dasboot
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.driver

spring.datasource.max-active=10
spring.datasource.max-idle=8
spring.datasource.max-wait=10000
spring.datasource.min-evictable-idle-time-millis=1000
spring.datasource.min-idle=8
spring.datasource.time-between-eviction-run-millis=1

flyway.baseline-on-migrate=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.jpa.shows-sql=true
```

Below is the query for H2 am using (V2__create_shipwreck.sql). This query is under **src/main/resources/db/migration** directory and am using maven packaging:

```
CREATE TABLE SHIPWRECK(
    ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    NAME VARCHAR(255),
    DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(2000),
    CONDITION VARCHAR(255),
    DEPTH INT,
    LATITUDE DOUBLE,
    LONGITUDE DOUBLE,
    YEAR_DISCOVERED INT
    );
```

in the final output console i expect to have a 'SCHEMA_VERSION' and my 'SHIPWRECk' table. But am getting nothing:
[image: H2 Console Output]

it would be great if someone can help me to resolve the same.

Comment: What does the application log says during spring boot start? There should be anything about flyway. Which version of flyway/spring boot do you use?

Comment: Update : i have solved this error

Comment: @Sunil what did you do to solve this issue? Would you post a solution please?

Comment: @AndrewD I recall doing a clean build of my Maven project and it solved the issue. I surely shall check more on the same and get back.